# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'number_records'

Tags: python, django

This is my forms:

```
class HistoryForm(UserSensitiveForm):

    number_records = forms.CharField(disabled=True,widget=Label())
    percentage_of_records = forms.CharField(disabled=True, widget=Label())

    class Meta:
        model = History
        fields = ['number_records','percentage_of_records']
        disabled_fields = ['number_records', 'percentage_of_records']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(HistoryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['percentage_of_records'] = forms.CharField(initial=self.instance.percentage_of_records, widget=Label(), disabled=True)
```

This is my models:

```
class History(models.Model):
    """The base model for history that are run"""


    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    rule = models.ForeignKey("Rule", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    job = models.ForeignKey("Job", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    number_records = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0)

    @property
    def percentage_of_records(self):
        percentage_of_records = History.objects.filter(job=self.job).aggregate(Sum('number_records'))['number_records__sum']
        return '{0:.2f}%'.format(percentage_of_records/self.job.number_records)
```

While run at UI getting above error.Any body can help in this.

And i have above in forms 
if self.instance is not None:
but it's still showing above error. i think, there generating none only.

Comment: Add full stack trace

Comment: You mean                                                                                                      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(HistoryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        try:                                                                       self.fields['percentage_of_records'] = forms.CharField(initial=self.instance.percentage_of_records, widget=Label(), disabled=True)

Comment: Can you give more detail of it.

Comment: `self.job` can be null in your db, null is converted to `None` in Python. Did you check that self.job is not None ?

Comment: It's showing error in this line                                                                    return '{0:.2f}%'.format(percentage_of_records/self.job.number_records)

Comment: I think self.job.number_reco‌​rds is none.for this can you please more detail

Comment: thx alot it's working fine